# Minor bug in substituting within a visual selection?

Tags: vim

There's really no reason to do the following (I did it only because I didn't think it through), but it may represent a bug in substitutions performed within a visual selection.

After visually selecting (`v`) an amount of text less than a line long, and starting a substitution (`:s`), and adding the visual selection atom (`\%V`), and choosing the catch-all regex (`.*`), the substitute string will look something like:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V.*/ /
```

(Here, replacing everything with a single space).  What I expected was everything within the visual selection to be replaced by a single space, but in fact, the entire line, including everything outside the visual selection, is replaced.  All other substitutions restrict themselves to the selection (e.g. `\a*` or just `.` )

I know there are some subtleties to the Vim regex atoms, and also to the delineators of visual selections (`'<` vs `` `< ``), so I wasn't sure if this is expected.  If it is expected, please let me know.  If not, it's certainly not a big deal because there are many better ways to do exactly the same thing, but I'll still go ahead and post to vim_dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From :help %V

> To make sure the whole pattern is inside the Visual area put it at the start and end of the pattern

```
'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V./ /
```

Should work. Note the extra dot, it's because vim excludes the last character of the selection for some reason.

Comment: SMH. I read that (small) help entry at least 3 times, but somehow managed to skip over that last sentence.  Thanks for the explanation about the extra dot as well (which does seem like a real minor bug).